# How to post data to https site

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, ssl-certificate, httpwebresponse

I'm a little stuck in how to generate a request which is to a https URL and uses a certificate for authentication.

When i try to navigate to the URL in a browser, i receive an error (**403 access denied**). As soon as i installed the **PFX** certificate (which requested a password), i was able to access the service.

I started with these links and adapted with what i thought was right

***Side note: you will see the cert below with the extension .cer. I exported the above certificate from a browser and then installed it within the Computer > Personal store (see MS link below).***

*http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28395/Attaching-a-digital-certificate-public-key-to-an-H
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/895971*

```
HttpWebRequest ThisReq = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("https://site/service");
    ThisReq.Method = "POST";
        ThisReq.ContentType = "application/xml";
        ThisReq.KeepAlive = true;

        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
    // Dont know if i need the below handler at this stage
        //ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new                    System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate);

        ThisReq.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password1");
        ThisReq.ClientCertificates.Clear();
        ThisReq.ClientCertificates.Add(X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(@"D:\cert.cer"));

        try
        {
            Resp = (System.Net.HttpResp)ThisReq.GetResponse();

        }
        catch (Exception we)
    {
    }
```

As soon as it executes `Resp = (System.Net.HttpResp)ThisReq.GetResponse();` i get the 403 error in the catch block. I tried looking at the request in Fiddler but nothing is apparent in there from what i could tell.

I've left some code out (like reading the XML file and passing in the bytes/content length) as it was throwing other errors - i can re-include this if any requires this.

Any help or examples to get this working would be great.

Edit 1:

Ipconfig results

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Win10Laptop
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : 
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : Home

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 3C-A9-F4-3F-DA-B9
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : Home
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Centrino(R) Ultimate-N 6300 AGN
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 3C-A9-F4-3F-DA-B8
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2a02:c7f:9809:b700:611c:8e4e:f3f8:9c2c(Preferred) 
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : fd7a:709e:7e57:0:611c:8e4e:f3f8:9c2c(Preferred) 
   Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : 2a02:c7f:9809:b700:653a:bde5:11f7:235b(Preferred) 
   Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : fd7a:709e:7e57:0:1d7c:4f97:c2a3:3208(Preferred) 
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::611c:8e4e:f3f8:9c2c%16(Preferred) 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.17(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 02 June 2016 09:03:44
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 03 June 2016 17:20:50
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::c23e:fff:fe78:a48%16
                                       192.168.1.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 121416180
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1D-4B-53-1D-F0-1F-AF-22-85-6C
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fd7a:709e:7e57:0:c23e:fff:fe78:a48
                                       192.168.1.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.Home:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : Home
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:9d38:6abd:1457:1b0b:681e:6e47(Preferred) 
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::1457:1b0b:681e:6e47%18(Preferred) 
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 201326592
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1D-4B-53-1D-F0-1F-AF-22-85-6C
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
```

Comment: Trace a connection using an IE using fiddler and then compare results with you c# application.  Compare the HTTP headers and make you c# code look like IE application.  An IE usually will default to http 1.0 while WebRequest defaults to http 1.1.  A lot of times simply adding : ThisReq.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10; will solve issue.

Comment: The problem i have with Fiddler doing this is - as soon as i load it and try to capture traffic i get a 403 error on the browser. Closing Fiddler resolves this but that means i cant look at the request made. I have tried re-installing but same issue

Comment: Can you reach the website with the browser when fiddler isn't running?  Does your PC have more than one Ethernet Connector?  One possibility is the server thinks you have more than one connection to the server.  I would go into IE history and delete all cookies and try again.  Fiddler also has an option (Clear Cache) which removes the cookies in fiddler but not in IE.  So you need to do both.  I think when you started fiddler you actually create a 2nd cookie with the same IP address so the server rejected the 2nd connection.

Comment: I have an ethernet, vEthernet & WiFi listed in Network Connections. I disabled all except WiFi and same issue. I can reach the site when fiddler is not running. As soon as i run fiddler i get the 403 error (same for other https sites). I've tried turning off the firewall too along with clearing the cache (including within fiddler)

Comment: Is fiddler set to the WiFi Interface?  I would like to see results from cmd.exe of following command : IPConfig -all.  Disabling doesn't necessarily will get you out the Wifi if the IP and masks are set up incorrectly.  Disabling may take an hour before the existing routes timeout and new ones take effect.

Comment: I've checked the options to see if fiddler is set to the WiFi interface but looking at the connections tab under options i see it set to DefaultLan (with it checked).I've added ipconfig results under the edit section of the original thread

Comment: All your IP is properly routed to your Wifi Geteway so I don't know why you are getting 403 with fiddler running.  It is also interesting that you get the same 403 error without fiddler using the httpRequest.  I'm not sure what is wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113667/discussion-between-computer-and-jdweng).